# Generating UniqueUserID with hashes

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to develop my own UniqueUserId generator, 
I need the ID to to be in this format:

```
99fbf2be-d41b-4c1c-e44e-c1fde9dd4738
```

This is my code:

```
    <?php

namespace OKO\OKOUniqueUserId;

use Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid;
use Rhumsaa\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;

class UniqueUserId
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @return Uuid
     */
    public function generate()
    {

        try {
            $this->uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
        } catch (UnsatisfiedDependencyException $e) {
            echo 'Error Generating User Unique ID';
        }

        return $this->uuid;
    }
}
```

MY OUTPYT LIKE THIS NOW:

```
object(Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid)#356 (1) { ["fields":protected]=> array(6) { ["time_low"]=> string(8) "d5a6efdf" ["time_mid"]=> string(4) "3f09" ["time_hi_and_version"]=> string(4) "416a" ["clock_seq_hi_and_reserved"]=> string(2) "b6" ["clock_seq_low"]=> string(2) "e8" ["node"]=> string(12) "7befe7820cb7" } }
```

but I still would expect this:

```
25769c6c-d34d-4bfe-ba98-e0ee856f3e7a
```

thx

Comment: Why don't you just [generate a proper UUID](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) as per [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)

Comment: OK when install UUID library through composer it is then installed in Vendor folder in my Symfony2 project how do I use it in my php classes...?

Comment: as shown [here](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/2.8/README.md#user-content-examples)

Comment: OK i go this installed, so it creates a directory for ramsay under my fector directory, the problem that i am having now is that ramsay in my vendor directory has a pad lock in meaning I cannot access it any idea why...?

Comment: OK i go tthis sorted Can you have a look at my edited question please one more issue remaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive a UUID object back from your method call, simply cast it to a string to invoke the objects __toString method:

```
$stringUuid = (string)$uuid;
```

Or there is a direct method if you would prefer that:

```
$stringUuid = $uuid->toString();
```